# assignment in prepareForSegue false

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to send a image to next scent.but failed.

here is my code

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue start");
    NSLog(@"count is %d",count);

    //bigStyle1 is a NSArray,full of UIImage
    //bigImage is a UIImageView outlet
    if ([bigStyle1 objectAtIndex:count]==nil) {
        NSLog(@"no array image");
    }
    viewController3.bigImage.image=[bigStyle1 objectAtIndex:count];
    if (viewController3.bigImage.image==nil) {
        NSLog(@"no controller image");
    }

    NSLog(@"secondToThird");        
    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue end");
}
```

here is Xcode's log

```
2013-03-12 15:15:38.683 animation[1876:f803] prepareForSegue start
2013-03-12 15:15:50.825 animation[1876:f803] count is 0
2013-03-12 15:17:10.829 animation[1876:f803] no controller image
```

It seems that the problem is in assignment of image.Why assignment failed?

**UPDATE**
viewController3 isn't nil.But bigImage is nil.I don't know why.I actually connect bigImage to the image view

Comment: are you sure `bigStyle1` is not null?

Comment: Is `viewController3` the destination of the segue? Where is the code that sets `viewController3`?

Comment: I'm sure bigStyle1 is not null.and viewController3 is instantiated by storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you intend `viewController3` to be the destination of the segue.  In that case, you should be setting it like this:

```
viewController3 = segue.destinationViewController;
```

I further suspect that `viewController3.bigImage` is a `UIImageView`.  If so, you have a problem because `viewController3` hasn't loaded its view hierarchy by the time the system sends `prepareForSegue:sender:`, so `viewController3.bigImage` hasn't been set yet.  It's nil, and setting a property on nil does nothing (with no warning or error message).

It would be better to give `viewController3` an `image` property directly, and store the image on that property.  Then, in `viewController3`'s `viewDidLoad` method, copy the image from that property to `self.bigImage.image`.

Alternatively, you can cheese it by forcing `viewController3` to load its view in `prepareForSegue:sender:` just by asking it for its view:

```
[viewController3 view];  // forces it to load its view hierarchy if necessary
viewController3.bigImage.image = [bigStyle1 objectAtIndex:count];
```